# Android: Downloading 1k+ images using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm currently trying to create an image "player" to show a person's drive. The drives are recorded and stored as images, split as 1 image per second.

I'm pulling the images using Glide. However, as you can imagine, there are a lot of images - thousands of them. My first idea was to download the images using the `downloadOnly` option of Glide, and use a `Discrete` Seekbar, and as the images are getting downloaded, then increase the max of the Seekbar. The problem with the approach, is that it takes a long time.

This is what I currently have to download the images:

```
    private void downloadOnlyImages(List<String> URLs){
    totalImages = 0;
    for(final String url: URLs){
        Glide.with(this)
             .load(url)
                .downloadOnly(new SimpleTarget<File>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(File resource, GlideAnimation<? super File> glideAnimation) {
                        Log.i("glide", "image downloaded" + url);
                        mySeekBar.setMax(totalImages++);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

and this is what I'm currently using with the seekbar:

```
                        mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                            Glide.with(getActivity())
                                    .load(URLs.get(progress))
                                    .fitCenter()
                                    .dontAnimate()
                                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                    .into(imageView);

                        }
```

The idea was, download the images, and then use the seekbar to move through them, always replacing the same `ImageView` with the next image. Using Glide's cache, I'm trying to check if it's in cache then pull that image if not then fetch using the URL. But, this hold up the UI Thread, which is causing the delay.

TLDR: I want to be able to be able to use a seekbar as a "player" for thousand of images that I'm pulling using Glide. However, it's very laggy using my naive approach. Trying to think of a more effective and efficient way to pull the images, in a more "lazy loading" way.

Comment: Try use Picasso with a Recycler View, he will download the image only when the adapter request the item, Picasso also uses cache.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro Would Picasso be much different than using Glide? I'm trying to think if my naive approach would work, or if there's something better than I'm missing.

Comment: To be honest, i never used Glide, i recommended Picasso because i think it's easy to integrate with a RecyclerView and load the image just when the view is requested, maybe Glide could do this too